# Open file content using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-ads-api

I have a object like this

```
{ 
   id: "114898379136253"
   leadgen_export_csv_url: "https://www.facebook.com/ads/lead_gen/export_csv/?id=379136253&type=form&source_type=graph_api",
   locale: "en_US"
   name: "Untitled form 11/7/2017"
   status: "ACTIVE"
}
```

I want get the file content, to fill my database with the leads that come from this file.

In my case, I need to treat the CORS also, because is a external URL, but I need some help in this solution, transform in a buffer and read the buffer? Or exist some better solution ?

```
   function loadFile(file) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', file, true);
        xhr.withCredentials = false;
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';

        xhr.onload = function (e) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.response);
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                console.log('DataURL:', e.target.result);
            };
        };

        xhr.send();
    }
```

The `DataURL:` in console log, return a Base64, and decoding the Base64 result, it returns me a webpage, but not the file.

Comment: You want that, but *what have you tried*?

Comment: @tadman some CORS request to open the file. I updated the question

Comment: That code makes for a much better question.

Comment: @tadman updated with some more information with what I get until now.